# OWASP scan on SQL Server Compact Edition

Tags: cve, sql-server, owasp, third-party

On running a dependency check on my projects library, the tool reported multiple vulnerabilities in `System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll`, and `CVE-2012-1856` with the highest score of 9.3

The version of the said DLL I have is from SQL Server Compact Edition 4.0 SP1 which I believe is the latest version available.

As I understand, the `Compact Edition` has now reached EOL. Could anyone confirm if this is the reason why the said vulnerabilities have not been patched? Are there any alternatives to SQL Server Compact Edition which can be used instead?

Comment: I ran the OWASP Dependency Check Command Line tool against the library and didn't report known vulnerabilities. Which scanner is reporting it as vulnerable?